# ajax success call back function within function ES6

Tags: ajax, es6-promise

I have a simple form. I submit it. I have a function called isSuccess that gets called when success happens. Within isSuccess I call a function testerit(). It never gets fired and complains it is undefined.
WHy is that

```
class FormSign {
    constructor(cfg) {
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        // listen for form submit
        $('.emailbtn').on('click', (event) = > {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.validateForm();
        });
    }
    submitForm() {
        //..............
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': '/api/url',
            'data': forminfo,
            'success': this.isSuccess,
            'error': this.isError
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    isSuccess() {
        //..............
        testerit();
    }
    signupError() {
        //...............
    }
    testerit() {
        console.log('just testing');
    }
}
```

Comment: is testerit a property of something or in a class? otherwise that's invalid syntax. same with isSuccess and signupError. You've given us code that doesn't run, there's not much we can do with it.

Comment: This is in the context of a class.

Comment: then you aren't referencing testerit properly.

Comment: whether i do this.testerit() or just testerit() it complains it is undefined

Comment: as it should, because neither of them are defined. `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: how and where do I define it?

Comment: you shouldn't define it, it already is defined on the instance. You just need to properly reference the instance.

Comment: when I reference it anywhere in the form even as 'complete':testerit it works fine. its only when I am calling it from within the isSuccess function where it complains about being undefined. as far as i can tell it appears to be referenced fine.

Comment: Right, the difference is where you're calling it from and how you are calling it. When you don't call it at all and instead *pass* it as an option to jQuery ajax, you're losing the instance and therefore can't call `this.testerit` because `this` isn't your instance inside said callback.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise. But curious why can't I call it just as testerit(); Shouldn't it already know that function exists in the code?

Comment: no... you defined it as a prototype method, so you've gotta call it as a property of the instance, otherwise it has no way of knowing which instance to act upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing an unbound function to jQuery's ajax success method, you've lost reference to your instance and therefore cannot call `this.testerit`. To remedy, you should either bind the instance to the function, or, give the instance to jQuery to use as a context.

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    context: this,
    'url': '/api/url',
    'data': forminfo,
    'success': this.isSuccess,
    'error': this.isError
})
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '/api/url',
    'data': forminfo,
    'success': data => this.isSuccess(data),
    'error': (jqXHR, status, error) => this.isError(jqXHR, status, error)
})
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '/api/url',
    'data': forminfo,
    'success': this.isSuccess.bind(this),
    'error': this.isError.bind(this)
})
```

and then properly call testerit on the instance.

```
this.testerit();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npc0nzjt/